# Unable to run WSO2 EI & MI as window services?

Tags: wso2, windows-services, wso2-enterprise-integrator, yajsw, wso2-micro-integrator

I have tried to install wso2 EI 6.5.0 & 6.6.0 and also MI 1.0 & 1.1.0 product as Windows service. While checking `runConsole.bat` itself throwing bulk exception.

If anyone faced same scenario means help me to get out from those exceptions.

6.6.0 Exception

````
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  Details:
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  Problematic reference = Reference[name = serverConfigurationService, interface = org.wso2.carbon.base.api.ServerConfigurationService, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 0..n, target = null, bind = setServerConfigurationService, unbind = unsetServerConfigurationService]
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  of service component = org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  component implementation class = org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl.internal.CryptoImplComponent
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  located in bundle with symbolic name = org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  bundle location = reference:file:../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl_1.1.2.jar java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
INFO|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|Trigger found: Exception in line: 
INFO|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|   bundle location = reference:file:../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl_1.1.2.jar java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
INFO|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|start script scripts/trayMessage.gv
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:376)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:444)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bind(ServiceComponentProp.java:218)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:343)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
INFO|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|end script scripts/trayMessage.gv
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/util/SecurityManager
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.wso2.carbon.base.ServerConfiguration.getSecuredDocumentBuilder(ServerConfiguration.java:523)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.wso2.carbon.base.ServerConfiguration.toDOM(ServerConfiguration.java:501)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.wso2.carbon.base.ServerConfiguration.getDocumentElement(ServerConfiguration.java:468)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  at org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl.internal.CryptoImplComponent.setServerConfigurationService(CryptoImplComponent.java:123)
INFO|216808/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|20-02-13 12:26:50|  ... 16 more```
````

[image: WSO2 MI 1.1.0 As windows Service Error log]

Comment: Can you paste the exception you are getting?

Comment: @ArunanSugunakumar I have pasted 6.6.0 Exception. Please have a look

Comment: @ArunanSugunakumar with 6.5.0 also i have faced some issues but it was resolved by deleting jars from `<EI_HOME>\dropins` and checked the slash(\\) properly in `<EI_HOME>\bin\yajsw\wrapper.conf`after that 6.5 Started properly as windows Service.

Comment: @ArunanSugunakumar any security patch needed for 6.6.0?

Comment: @ArunanSugunakumar should work with jdk 11 & yajsw 12.14 or with jdk 8 & yajsw 12.14

Comment: Should work in both cases...

Comment: @ArunanSugunakumar tried with both cases. Facing the issues with both cases

Comment: What is the Windows version you are using? Also are you using any SecureVault configurations?

Comment: @ArunanSugunakumar My windows version is windows 10 - 64 bit. SecureVault Configurations means which one you are asking?

Comment: @ArunanSugunakumar yajsw12.14 is used to install MI 1.1.0 as a Windows Service?

Answer (score 0):

There are some recent changes made to the documentation of EI 6.6.0. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Running+the+Product+as+a+Windows+Service

Can you confirm whether you followed all the steps in this particular doc?

Please take note of the below points

> WSO2 recommends Yet Another Java Service Wrapper (YAJSW) version
>   12.14. If you are running on JDK 11, previous versions of YAJSW will not be compatible.

Also,

> Step 1: Setting up the YAJSW wrapper

Comment: Thank you. Will check and confirm you. Now i have yajsw 11.03 Stable version & jdk 8 (installed in my system).

Comment: Did you try out with the wrapper.conf mentioned in the doc and with yajsw 12.14?

Comment: Yes i have tried. I added MI 1.1.0 as windows service Error snippet, please check

Comment: I tried out this scenario with EI 6.6.0 in a Windows 10 instance. I installed OracleJDK8 and used YASJSW 12.14 with the minimal wrapper.conf provided in the documentation. The server started successfully.

Comment: Further digging I also found a similar issue, which has been fixed before the release of EI 6.6.0 https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/4825 Please check whether the fix is available in your bat file.